# Why JBoss EAP failed to start?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm new to JBoss Server. Currently I'm using JBoss server 7.2.

**Error :**

```
09:25:05,213 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.6.Final-redhat-00001
09:25:05,646 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001
09:25:05,654 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final-redhat-1
09:25:05,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) starting
09:25:06,526 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.6.1.Final-redhat-00001
09:25:08,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) OPVDX002: Failed to pretty print validation error: null
09:25:08,737 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:377)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:372)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'T' (code 84) excepted space, or '>' or "/>"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [156,86]
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:650)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:204)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.3.0.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.3.0.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_8.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml_8.java:607)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_8.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_8.java:240)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_8.readElement(StandaloneXml_8.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.3.0.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.3.0.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'T' (code 84) excepted space, or '>' or "/>"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [156,86]
    at org.codehaus.woodstox//com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:653)
    at org.codehaus.woodstox//com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3076)
    at org.codehaus.woodstox//com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3043)
    at org.codehaus.woodstox//com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2919)
    at org.codehaus.woodstox//com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1123)
    at org.codehaus.woodstox//com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1204)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper@1.3.0.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:189)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:643)
    ... 14 more

09:25:08,740 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
09:25:08,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0050: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) stopped in 8ms
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `standalone.xml` or `standalone-full.xml`.

**Please validate your xml whether it's right or wrong.**

[Here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) validate your xml.

That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Yes it's about datasource config in standalone.xml :))
Thank youu

Comment: Ah @Anish, can you take a look at the error also( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997441/run-into-error-when-deploy-ear-file-into-jboss-eap-7-2). Thanks in advance :D