# Run into error when deploy .ear file into JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, redhat

Can anyone tell me what did it happen? I just cannot deploy my .ear file due to this error :((

**Error log in JBoss console**

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"tpfx.ear\".\"tpfx.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local"}}
```

**Detail log in eclipse's console**

```
14:02:27,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'CounterpartyBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyLocal
    java:module/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyLocal
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyRemote
    java:module/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/CounterpartyBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.CounterpartyRemote

14:02:27,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ReportBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportLocal
    java:module/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportLocal
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportRemote
    java:module/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReportBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReportRemote

14:02:27,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'UserBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserLocal
    java:module/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserLocal
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserRemote
    java:module/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/UserBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UserRemote

14:02:27,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ReprintResendBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendLocal
    java:module/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendLocal
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendRemote
    java:module/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/ReprintResendBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ReprintResendRemote

14:02:27,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'RFQBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQLocal
    java:module/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQLocal
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQRemote
    java:module/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/RFQBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.RFQRemote

14:02:27,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'MarketBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketLocal
    java:module/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketLocal
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketRemote
    java:module/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/MarketBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.MarketRemote

14:02:27,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'TradeBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeRemote
    java:module/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeRemote
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeLocal
    java:module/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/TradeBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.TradeLocal

14:02:27,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'DataBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "tpfx-ejb.jar" of deployment "tpfx.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataRemote
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataRemote
    java:module/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataRemote
    java:jboss/exported/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataRemote
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataRemote
    java:global/tpfx/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataLocal
    java:app/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataLocal
    java:module/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataLocal
    ejb:tpfx/tpfx-ejb/DataBean!com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.DataLocal

14:02:27,654 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment tpfx.war
14:02:27,857 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000900: 3.0.5 (redhat)
14:02:28,375 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
14:02:28,873 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flow] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
14:02:28,884 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
14:02:29,117 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001 for context '/tpfx'
14:02:30,007 INFO  [org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.serialization.JBossSerializationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Using JBoss Serialization for JavaServer Faces.
14:02:30,560 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."tpfx.ear"."tpfx.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."tpfx.ear"."tpfx.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    at deployment.tpfx.ear.tpfx.war//com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.web.servlet.TPFXContextListener.contextInitialized(TPFXContextListener.java:121)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    at deployment.tpfx.ear.tpfx.war//com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.web.DataDelegate.<init>(DataDelegate.java:49)
    at deployment.tpfx.ear.tpfx.war//com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.web.servlet.TPFXContextListener.contextInitialized(TPFXContextListener.java:99)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    at deployment.tpfx.ear.tpfx-ejb.jar//com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocator.lookup(ServiceLocator.java:51)
    at deployment.tpfx.ear.tpfx.war//com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.web.DataDelegate.<init>(DataDelegate.java:47)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:159)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:239)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at deployment.tpfx.ear.tpfx-ejb.jar//com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocator.lookup(ServiceLocator.java:44)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbLookupInjectionSource$1.getReference(EjbLookupInjectionSource.java:99)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:143)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:237)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbLookupInjectionSource$1.getReference(EjbLookupInjectionSource.java:81)
    ... 33 more

14:02:30,565 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "tpfx.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"tpfx.ear\".\"tpfx.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local"}}
14:02:30,567 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "tpfx.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"tpfx.ear\".\"tpfx.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.UnavailableException: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: com.tesla.cmb.tpfx.business.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/DataLocal [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: tpfx/DataBean/local -- service jboss.naming.context.java.tpfx.DataBean.local"}}
14:02:30,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: tpfx-ejb.jar) in 86ms
14:02:31,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: tpfx.war) in 617ms
14:02:31,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment tpfx.ear (runtime-name: tpfx.ear) in 628ms
14:08:35,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYDR0009: Content D:\Users\tu_thanh.d\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\data\content\de\08e4aa1014efd6f3ca8b843c1b0e3b39ea7606 is obsolete and will be removed
14:08:35,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location D:\Users\tu_thanh.d\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\data\content\de\08e4aa1014efd6f3ca8b843c1b0e3b39ea7606\content
```

Comment: Looking into error

Comment: Add the code base

Comment: Ok I will search more about it. Thank @Anish :D